# awk printing random "e" that is not in string

Tags: bash, awk, tmsh

I am wanting to extract ip and port from a string.

Strings look like this.

destination x.x.x.x:yyyy

where x is ip and y is port

```
    commandout=()
    while IFS= read -r line # Read a line
    do
        commandout+=("$line") # Append line to the array
    done < <(tmsh list ltm virtual $vip | grep destination)
    for output in "$commandout";
    do
        if [[ $output == *"destination"* ]];then
            #split off ip and port
            ipport=$(echo $output | awk 'BEGIN{}{print $2}')
            echo $ipport | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}'
            echo $ipport
        fi
    done
    declare -p commandout
```

for some reason, awk is printing a random "e" after the ip address.  But it only appears to do so after 2.

```
10.10.10.10
10.10.10.10:https
declare -a commandout='([0]="    destination 10.10.10.10:https")'
12.12.12.12e
12.12.12.12:https
declare -a commandout='([0]="    destination 12.12.12.12:https")'
```

UPDATE:

So I attempted another test.  I found strange behavior and I am unsure how to fix it.

I declare the vipip before and after it is set.

```
    declare -p vipip
    vipip=$(tmsh list ltm virtual $vip | grep destination | awk 'BEGIN{}{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}')
    echo $vipip
    declare -p vipip
    echo "cyle loop"
```

results in the following.  Note that the 12.12.12.12 doesn't have an "e" on the end of it

```
./findvips-final.scr: line 240: declare: vipip: not found
10.10.10.10
declare -- vipip="10.10.10.10"
cyle loop
declare -- vipip="10.10.10.10"
12.12.12.12
declare -- vipip="12.12.12.12"
cyle loop
```

If I comment out the declare statements, I get an "e"

```
    #declare -p vipip
    vipip=$(tmsh list ltm virtual $vip | grep destination | awk 'BEGIN{}{print $2}' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"}{print $1}')
    echo $vipip
    #declare -p vipip
    echo "cyle loop"
```

results in

```
10.10.10.10
cyle loop
12.12.12.12e
cyle loop
```

I found the answer.  I have a progress meter above this and I was getting the e off of complete.

```
echo -ne "$((100*$z/$count))% Complete\r"
```

I wrapped $vipip in qoutes on the echo and it is working like I thought.  UGh wait a big waste of time.

Comment: `declare -a commandout='([0]="    destination 10.10.10.10:https")'` `declare -a commandout='([0]="    destination 12.12.12.12:https")'`

Comment: the current approach seems to be overcomplicated for such simple task

Comment: Please show us the sample Input_file and expected output here, it will be easy for us to help then.

Comment: I expanded the code.  you can see the output is coming from a command issues to the appliance.

Comment: `for output in "$commandout"` should be: `for output in "${commandout[@]}"` but you should also output of `tmsh list ltm virtual "$vip"` command in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can straightaway set `FS` like below to extract Ip from your command, no need of loop, `awk` can search string also

```
your_command | awk -F'[ :]' '/destination/{gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$2); print $2}'
```

**Explanation**

`-F'[ :]'` - set field separator

`'/destination/` - search for word destination in line/record/row

`gsub(/[^0-9.]/,"",$2)` - remove anything other than number and dot from second field ( so that random char like `e`, what you said above will be removed )

`print $2` - print second field

Comment: I tried that command, it doesn't work.  Does it assume the output is already on 1 line?  output is multi-row.  `| grep destination` gets the line I need

Comment: if output is multiple row also does not matter